# Arbitrarily small lengths of segments inside convex polygon

Tags: geometry, contest-math, combinatorial-geometry

> Given an integer $n\ge 3$, a real number $\alpha>0$, and a set of real
> numbers with finitely many elements $ S= \{ k_1,k_2,...,k_r\}$, show that
> there exists a convex polygon with $n$ lattice vertices (that is,
> whose every vertex belongs to $\mathbb{Z}^2$), such that for any segment
> inside this polygon, if its slope is in $S$, its length will not exceed
> $\alpha$.
>
> (Proposed by 虫仙).

I don't know if I understood the problem well, I think we could just get a very small regular $ n$-gon (with main diagonal less than $a$).

Since the vertices are lattice points, a diagonal measures at least $\sqrt{2}$, which is larger than $a$ if for example $a=0.1$.

This problem is from the NGC Girls MO.

Comment: You’re right, as the problem is written, a small polygon suffices. I can’t find the contest you got this from. Do you have the original redaction?

Comment: @URL (Proposed by 虫仙) :  2019 NGC Girls MO, Day 1, Problem 3

Comment: This feels like there may be a misinterpretation as we don't need to consider much as we choose a circle with radius $\frac{a}{2}$ and inscribe any polygon.

Comment: @oshill Because all of these verteces are lattice points, its circum radius is at least $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$.
$a$ can be arbitrarily small. Thus, please reconsider the problem.

Comment: @Tortugot Do you mean to say that the vertices of the polygon must lie in the integer lattice $\mathbb{Z}^2$? If so you should specify this in your initial problem statement (first paragraph) to be clear.

Comment: @JairTaylor Thank you so much for enlightening me

Comment: The problem in the updated redaction is essentially to prove that we can make a lattice polygon arbitrarily “thin” in any finite amount of directions. That might be easier to wrap your head around.

Comment: @URL Yep. I think you are on the right track. The rest is just some approximation to show “arbitrarily thin” is achievable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:** After talking with a friend about this problem, I realized that I actually just solved the case $n=3$. The general case, however, follows directly: we can take a triangle satisfying the problem's conditions for the length $\frac\alpha n$, and scale it up by a factor of $n$. By extending its long side, we can create $n-1$ rows of points in the triangle's interior. This is more than enough to build a convex lattice $n$-gon, which will satisfy the problem's constraints, being in the interior of a triangle that does.

The problem essentially asks us to prove that, for every set of directions, there exists a convex lattice polygon as “thin” as we want it to in every of those directions. To prove this, we’ll construct a lattice triangle satisfying our constraints, for every choice of $S$, $\alpha$.

To do this, we’ll need two lemmas.

**Lemma $\mathbf1$:**

For every segment $\ell$ of slope $\frac pq$ connecting two lattice points, with $p$, $q$ coprime integers, there exists a lattice point $A$ at a distance of no more than $\frac 1q$ of $\ell$.

**Proof:**

Consider the leftmost extreme of $\ell$, with coordinates $(x,y)$. If $\frac pq=\frac01$, then $A=(x+1,y)$ suffices. Otherwise, let $0\leq a<q$ be a multiplicative inverse of $p\bmod q$. The lattice point $A=\left(x+a,y+\frac{ap-1}q\right)$ is at a distance of $\frac 1q$ from the point $\left(x+a,y+\frac{ap}q\right)\in\ell$, so that the distance from $A$ to $\ell$ does not exceed our desired amount. $\square$

**Lemma $\mathbf2$:**

For every $\bigtriangleup ABC$ and every $m$, if the cevian $AX$ with slope $m$ is contained in $\bigtriangleup ABC$, it is the longest segment with such slope inside of the triangle.

**Proof:**

Take a segment $PQ$ of slope $m$ inside $\bigtriangleup ABC$. We can extend it to a segment $P’Q’$ whose endpoints are in the perimeter of the triangle. This segment will either be contained in $\bigtriangleup ABX$ or in $\bigtriangleup ACX$. Either way, it will be smaller than $AX$, by Thales. $\square$

---

We’re now ready to begin our construction.

For every $m\in S$, we can create an associated angle $0\leq m_a<\pi$, that represents the (directed) angle of a line with slope $m$ with respect to the horizontal. We’ll call the set of all of these angles $S_a$.

Now, we can consider an arbitrary $\theta\not\in S_a$. Let $2\varepsilon$ be the smallest distance ($\text{mod }\pi$) from $\theta$ to any element of $S_a$. Since $\mathbb Q$ is dense in $\mathbb R$, we can take a line $\ell$ through two lattice points with slope $\frac pq$, with $p$, $q$ coprime integers, such that $\ell$ makes a (directed) angle with the horizontal between $\theta-\varepsilon$ and $\theta+\varepsilon$ ($\text{mod }\pi$), and such that $$q\geq\frac1{\sin(\varepsilon)\alpha}.$$ By **lemma $\mathbf1$**, we can take a lattice point $A$ at a distance of $d\leq\frac 1q$ from $\ell$. Then, we can take lattice points $B$ and $C$ in $\ell$ “far enough”, so that the resulting $\bigtriangleup ABC$ contains cevians from $A$ with all slopes in $S$. Finally, by **lemma $\mathbf2$**, the length of any segment in $\bigtriangleup ABC$ with a slope $m\in S$ will not exceed the length of the corresponding cevian $AX$, which measures $$\frac d{\sin(\angle AXB)}\leq\frac d{\sin(\varepsilon)}\leq\frac1{q\sin(\varepsilon)}\leq\alpha,$$ just as we wanted. $\blacksquare$

Comment: SpecialBeing2017 on AoPS has [another solution](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1955937p13514386), quite different to mine and good in its own right. Also, someone on that thread just blatantly copy-pasted this answer 11 minutes after I posted mine. That's certainly a thing.